# Accessing Request from __init__.py in Pyramid

Tags: python, logging, request, pyramid

When setting up a Pyramid app and adding settings to the Configurator, I'm having issues understanding how to access information from request, like request.session and such. I'm completely new at using Pyramid and I've searched all over the place for information on this but found nothing.

What I want to do is access information in the request object when sending out exception emails on production. I can't access the request object, since it's not global in the `__init__.py` file when creating the app. This is what I've got now:

```
import logging
import logging.handlers
from logging import Formatter

config.include('pyramid_exclog')
logger = logging.getLogger()

gm = logging.handlers.SMTPHandler(('localhost', 25), 'email@email.com', ['email@email.com'], 'Error')
gm.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
logger.addHandler(gm)
```

This works fine, but I want to include information about the logged in user when sending out the exception emails, stored in session. How can I access that information from `__init__.py`?

Comment: from your code I can't understand how you would expect exception emails to be generated. if you are planning on sending emails when exceptions are raised you should look into custom exception views. http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/views.html?awesome#custom-exception-views it's a view so you will have the current request at that time and you would probably want to send the email there and then generate an error response.

Comment: Perhaps you could create an event subscriber that listens on `NewRequest` http://www.kemeneur.com/clients/pylons/docs/pyramid/narr/events.html#events-chapter?

Comment: @TomWillis I'm using the pyramid_exclog (http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid_exclog/en/latest/) to handle logging, so by adding a SMTPHandler to the logging handlers there it's a convenient way of having all the logging code in one place. The exception emails are generated, working fine, that's not the problem I'm having :)

Comment: Good point from @Sergey below about creating an event subscriber that listens on `NewRequest`. It might not be a good idea for production.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Attempting to make request a global variable, or somehow store a pointer to "current" request globally (if that's what you're going to try with subscribing to `NewRequest` event) is not a terribly good idea - a Pyramid application can have more than one thread of execution, so more than one request can be active within a single process at the same time. So the approach may appear to work during development, when the application runs in a single thread mode and just one user accesses it, but produce really funny results when deployed to a production server.

Pyramid has `pyramid.threadlocal.get_current_request()` function which returns thread-local request variable, however, the docs state that:

> This function should be used extremely sparingly, usually only in unit
>   testing code. it’s almost always usually a mistake to use
>   get_current_request outside a testing context because its usage makes
>   it possible to write code that can be neither easily tested nor
>   scripted.

which suggests that the whole approach is not "pyramidic" (same as pythonic, but for Pyramid :)

Possible other solutions include:

- look at [exlog.extra_info](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid_exclog/en/latest/#settings) parameter which should include environ and params attributes of the request into the log message
- registering exception views would allow completely custom processing of exceptions
- Using WSGI middleware, such as `WebError#error_catcher` or `Paste#error_catcher` to send emails when an exception occurs
- if you want to log not only exceptions but possibly other non-fatal information, maybe just writing a wrapper function would be enough:

  ```
  if int(request.POST['donation_amount']) >= 1000000:
     send_email("Wake up, we're rich!", authenticated_userid(request))
  ```

Comment: Thanks for the great answer @Sergey!  
exclog.extra_info does give me more information, but it doesn't dig down into the context object or give me information out of a user object, for an example. The information I'd like to send with the exception is hidden in there.  
But going through your possible solutions I think the only thing I'm left with that will work is registering custom exception views and handling it there.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but from what I can gather pyramid only allows custom exception views for exceptions in pyramid.exceptions (see: http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/1.0-branch/api/exceptions.html). So that basically means I can't use custom exception views for this example to work.

Comment: Have a look at http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/views.html?awesome#custom-exception-views - the example shows registering a custom view to an exception which is directly subclassed from `Exception`